# Anonymous function in lapply

Tags: r, lapply

I am reading Wickham's Advanced R book. This question is relating to solving Question 5 in chapter 12 - Functionals. The exercise asks us to:

> Implement a version of `lapply()` that supplies FUN with both the name and value of each component.

Now, when I run below code, I get expected answer for one column.

```
c(class(iris[1]),names(iris[1]))
```

Output is:

```
"data.frame"   "Sepal.Length"
```

Building upon above code, here's what I did:

```
lapply(iris,function(x){c(class(x),names(x))})
```

However, I only get the output from `class(x)` and not from `names(x)`. Why is this the case?

I also tried `paste()` to see whether it works.

```
lapply(iris,function(x){paste(class(x),names(x),sep = " ")})
```

I only get `class(x)` in the output. I don't see `names(x)` being returned.

Why is this the case? Also, how do I fix it?

Can someone please help me?

Comment: A vector has no `names` attributes. Compare `names(iris[1])` vs `names(iris[,1])` (the first one is still a dataframe, while the second one is a vector). Your function would work if you'd give it something meaningful such as  `lapply(iris,function(x){c(class(x),length(x))})`. Also, SO is about creating a knowledge data base in order to help future readers too, not just you. Hence title such as "*A mysterious function in the secret garden*" are not searchable and hence aren't helpful to anyone except yourself.

Comment: @David. Thanks. I did change the title. My apologies about this. Is there anyway, I can get individual column names? I'd appreciate your help.

Comment: @DavidArenburg "A vector has no names attributes." In this example there is none, but a vector *can*  have a `names` attribute: `setNames(1:3, letters[1:3])`.

Comment: @Roland I know a vector can have a name attribute. In fact it can even have a "Roland" attribute (e.g., `x <- 1:3 ; data.table::setattr(x, "Roland", "sup"))` I was just trying to explain OP why his function doesn't work.

Comment: @DavidArenburg I know that you know. But I don't know if OP does.

Comment: @DavidArenburg Btw, you can set it with base R: `attr(x, "David") <- "hi"`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Instead of going over the data frame directly you could switch things around and have lapply go over a vector of the column names,

```
data(iris)

lapply(colnames(iris), function(x) c(class(iris[[x]]), x))
```

or over an index for the columns, referencing the data frame.

```
lapply(1:ncol(iris), function(x) c(class(iris[[x]]), names(iris[x])))
```

Notice the use of both single and double square brackets.
`iris[[n]]` references the values of the `n`th object in the list `iris` (a data frame is just a particular kind of list), stripping all attributes, making something like `mean(iris[[1]])` possible.
`iris[n]` references the `n`th object itself, all attributes intact, making something like `names(iris[1])` possible.